# Getting user follower's on Twitter from the end of the "list"

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Unfortunately the process of getting the followers of a user failed somewhere in the middle (400k or so followers in total). I was wondering if there was any way to start this process from the other side of the spectrum, i.e. from the end of the list. As explained [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-list), currently the results are ordered with the most recent following first. Is it possible to start the process from the end of this list (since I already got the first half)? The above-mentioned documentation page doesn't indicate anything but I thought I'd ask once.

Comment: Where is your program? What is the issue, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the documentation that you linked, the GET followers/list endpoint does not accept any parameters that would change the order of the results. This isn't something Twitter's API supports.

If you have the `previous_cursor` or `next_cursor` for your last page of results, you can pass that to the endpoint as the `cursor` parameter to continue where you left off.